# function (err) callback in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm still trying to wrap my head around what are function callback and how it works. I understand that it is a vital part of javascript. For example this method writeFile from node.js documentation, what does this function callback do? How can this function have an input for `err`?

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

Comment: Functions are objects. You're *passing* the function object to the `writeFile` method. That method receives it, and at the right time, it calls it, passing a value to the `err` parameter. If there was no error to report, it'll probably pass `null` or `undefined`. I don't remember which.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fs.writeFile` will pass an `error` to your callback function as `err` in the event an error happens.

Consider this example

```
function wakeUpSnorlax(done) {

  // simulate this operation taking a while
  var delay = 2000;

  setTimeout(function() {

    // 50% chance for unsuccessful wakeup
    if (Math.round(Math.random()) === 0) {

      // callback with an error
      return done(new Error("the snorlax did not wake up!"));
    }

    // callback without an error
    done(null);        
  }, delay);
}

// reusable callback
function callback(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
  else {
    console.log("the snorlax woke up!");
  }
}

wakeUpSnorlax(callback); 
wakeUpSnorlax(callback); 
wakeUpSnorlax(callback);
```

2 seconds later ...

```js
the snorlax did not wake up!
the snorlax did not wake up!
the snorlax woke up!
```

In the example above, `wakeUpSnorlax` is like `fs.writeFile` in that it takes a callback function to be called when fs.writeFile is done. If `fs.writeFile` detects and error during any of its execution, it can send an `Error` to the callback function. If it runs without any problem, it will call the callback without an error.

Comment: @naomik `Number.isNaN('x') -> false`. Fix it.

Comment: @sza, i forgot the `parseInt` in there.

Comment: Is it common to add the function(err) in your code? I assume it will help with debugging.

Comment: @user2724559 The callback is the nature of JavaScript due the the asynchronous control flow. And using callback is the only way you can chain the operations together synchronously.